# Did the aliens cause the rare and incurable disease?

Tags: arrival

In the 2016 American science fiction drama film Arrival, aside from what seems to be a type of cancer in Hannah, we also can see how she limps and at some point, she asks her mom Louise to help her with one of her boots. Given that Louise was the only character that kept direct contact with the heptapods and survived, is there any evidence to support the idea that this contact caused a kind of infection in Louise's body that resulted in Hannah's disease?

Comment: Her husband also survived, as did a bunch of other people on the other teams

Comment: @Valorum Louise was the only human to take the rock elevator up and meet with the heptapods "behind the glass," in their own environment; Ian and the other researchers were always on the human side of the glass.  And exposure to teratogens doesn't necessarily harm the people exposed to them.

Comment: [Glamour](https://www.glamour.com/story/amy-adams-arrival-movie-review) suggests this is so, but without evidence: "Hannah will die of a rare illness that, the film suggests, was caused by her parents’ exposure to the aliens before Hannah was even conceived."

Comment: “Is there any evidence?” Not in the film itself, no. You’ve watched it, I assume? Are you asking if you missed anything?

Comment: @all - I wonder if the final meeting between Louise and the heptapods affected some of her genes whose effect was manifested later as a disease in Hannah. Thanks.

Comment: The novella isn't useful here because the child died of an accident rather than a disease there.